# Modifying log4j.properties file on AWS Elastic MapReduce

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I'm using AWS Elastic MapReduce and I would like to be able to set the logging level. For example, I would like for log.isDebugEnabled() to return true. A bit of googling led me to find this blog article:

http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/an-approach-to-controlling-logging-on-amazon-web-services-aws-elastic-mapreduce-emr/

which basically suggests writing a shell script to copy and overwrite the local log4j.properties file. This seems like a complicated approach. I would prefer a simpler way of setting the debug level. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 other ways:

1. Using `hadoop daemonlog -setlevel` command one can set the logging level for a given Hadoop daemon and classname.
2. Visit the jobtracker's web UI and set the log name's level. 
   The web UI url would be :
   `http://<host:port>/logLevel`

but both these ways only set the log levels for the timespan till the daemons are running, as soon as they are restarted, they will pick-up the one's in log4j.properties.

Read more [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Wu_xeGdU4G8C&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq=hadoop%20set%20log%20level&source=bl&ots=i7BNVwXfXq&sig=51bNyjX1KFLzqPzXLCwcviU0tG8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e7FZUsDpOIeZiQfM24GoDg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=hadoop%20set%20log%20level&f=false).

Comment: Thanks, although I do still have a question. In the book you linked to, it says add     log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker=DEBUG in the configuration directory. Should this configuration be part of the jar I upload?

Comment: No, it should be added in hadoop's installation directory's conf : `<hadoop_root>/conf/log4j.properties`.